# Why I have only one table after runing Entity Framework migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following set of models:

User:

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public string SocialId { get; set; }

    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpirationAccess { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpirationRefresh { get; set; }

    public string AuthType { get; set; }

    public decimal Money { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

        AccessToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        RefreshToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        ExpirationAccess = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
        ExpirationRefresh = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);
    }
}
```

Recipes:

```
public class Recipe
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User Author { get; set; }

    public int LikesCount { get; set; }

    public int DislikesCount { get; set; }

    public int Time { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Ingridient> Ingridients { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RecipeStep> Steps { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public int ServingsCount { get; set; }

    public int Image { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public Recipe()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        UpdatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

All models is here.

[image]

When I running `dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration` I have migration for creating only one table `Users`. Here is the text of the migration that was generated:

```
public partial class InitialMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Users",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn),
                Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                UpdatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                SocialId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                AccessToken = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                RefreshToken = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ExpirationAccess = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                ExpirationRefresh = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                AuthType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Money = table.Column<decimal>(nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.Id);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Users");
    }
}
```

It looks like as migrations for only `Users` table. But where is the rest? And when I'm running `dotnet ef database update` I have only one table `Users`. 
[image]

So what is wrong? I'm newbie in EF, and maybe I don't understand how it works. Can you describe me how to generate all tables from my models?

P.S. 
The platform is .Net Core 2.2.300. Project type is Web API. Database is PostgreSQL.

### Update

My db context is

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ApplicationContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Recipes");
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

I've injected it via standard DI system

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
       .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthService, AuthService>();
    }
```

Comment: Have you added the other model classes to the DBContext?

Comment: Show your context class.

Comment: I've added my db context in the answer. But I don't understand where I have to use it? I used it in Services and simple Controllers before.

Comment: In order for EF to create the tables, you have to add them to a context as a DbSet. Otherwise EF has no idea these classes should be in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added a set of `User` to your DbContext.

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

You've not added a set of `Recipe`. That's why you have a migration for `User` but not `Recipe`. Add one for recipe and then either regenerate the migration by reversing it and recreating it, or add another to compound the changes.

```
public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
```

Note: You *can* get entities mapped and migrating without adding `DbSet<>` to the `DbContext` but it involves setting up the entity in `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: Ohhhh. Thank you) I just forgot about it) It works and I can see all tables with relations) Thank you again))